# How to Show Popup window on clicking dynamically generated link

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysqli

> T have one page on which results are get created dynamically. And I
>   want to display popup window on clicking image named view.jpg. The
>   image is hyperlink. So please tell me how should i do it. I am showing
>   my code as follows.

code :

```
echo "<table width='' height='' border='1' align='center'>
        <tr><td>Title</td>
            <td >Type</td>
            <td >Date</td>
            <td>Expiry Date</td>";
            if($typeofuser=='admin' || $typeofuser=='Accountant' || $typeofuser=='secretary')
            {
            echo "<td>View</td>
            <td>Edit</td>
            <td>Delete</td>";
            }
        echo "</tr>";

            $qry2 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT nId,nTitle,nDescription,nDate,nExpiryDate FROM tblnoticemanager where Society_id = '$socId' and category='General'") or die(mysqli_error($con));
                while($NoticeData = mysqli_fetch_array($qry2))
                {
                echo "<tr>"; 
                    echo  "<td align='center' class='tdletter' style='text-transform:capitalize;'>" .$NoticeData['nTitle']. "</td>";
                    echo  "<td align='center' class='tdletter' ><div class='overflowDiv'>" . $NoticeData['nDescription']."</div></td>"; 
                    echo  "<td align='center' class='tdletter'>" . $NoticeData['nDate'] ."</td>"; 
                    echo  "<td align='center' class='tdletter'>" . $NoticeData['nExpiryDate'] ."</td>";
                    if($typeofuser=='admin' || $typeofuser=='Accountant' || $typeofuser=='secretary')
                    {
                    echo  "<td align='center' class='tdletter'><div><a href='?id=".urlencode(base64_encode($NoticeData['nId']))."'><img src='images/view.png' width='30' height='30' align='center' /></a></div></td>";
                    echo  "<td align='center' class='tdletter'><div><a href='?id=".urlencode(base64_encode($NoticeData['nId']))."' ><img src='images/edit.jpg' width='30' height='30' align='center'/></a></div></td>";  
                    echo  "<td align='center' class='tdletter'><span id='".$NoticeData['nId']."' class='trash'><img src='images/delete1.jpg' width='30' height='30' align='center' /></span></td>";
                    }
                echo "</tr>";              
                 }          
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: implement simple pop-up box & pass dynamic id to it

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**attribute selector `[attribute='value']`**](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

```
$("[src='images/view.png']").click(function(){
     alert("clicked");
});
```